# What is the best option to bind/edit data using DXGrid from MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I'm trying to bind DXGrid control to an IList. Though binding works perfectly fine some other features of the grid are not working like those of Auto filter row, and In-line editing.

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DataSource="{Binding Path=Model, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:GridColumnView x:Name="gridView" AllowEditing="True" AllowFilter="True" ShowAutoFilterRow="True" AutoWidth="True" ShowGroupPanel="False" />
</dxg:GridControl.View>
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CountryCode"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CountryName" AutoFilterCondition="Like"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CurrencyCode"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CurrencyName"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Active"/>
</dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

What is the best option to bind/edit data using DXGrid and MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might consider binding against an implementation of [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx). A very good blog post describing the interface can be found [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/).